# Azure Kubernetes - Local Kubernetes Environment for Developers?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have installed Docker desktop to build the image however how do I setup the Kubernetes on my local machine to deploy and test? My application depends on configmap, secrets, cronjobs and PV, PVCs. Is there any development space available on Azure Kubernetes? If so, how do I use it?

Comment: Docker Desktop's built-in Kubernetes support is a fine starting point, especially if you need only "normal" Kubernetes resources like the ones you list.  Or else a local Kubernetes installation like minikube or kind.

Comment: How do I deploy it using docker desktop? Does it support kubectl?

Comment: The [Docker Desktop for Mac user manual](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#kubernetes) discusses this a little (works the same on Windows); yes, it supports `kubectl` and other standard Kubernetes tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can likely explore azure dev spaces for this, that's specifically designed to escort developers and make their life easy.

A namespace and subspaces are created inside that, the subspaces are used by individual developers to work on by marking the respective subspaces active for them, anytime you change the code, it will build the docker image and deploy the code to that space.

The only thing is that it is present in preview feature, hence likely you have to explore it for your specific use cases.

You can likely check for this at azure portal

Comment: Thank you, is this  the normal way of building or using the kubernetes development environment?

Comment: the other approach can be to have minikube but that is to be self managed while azure dev spaces will be all together managed services from azure